# Cannot modify the properties of any IBOutlets within file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iboutlet

Currently I'm in an AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate, with a storyboard created method of presenting the data to the user. However, when  I call a method from another view controller to pass the data between the two, I can retrieve the data just fine and NSLog it accordingly but cannot assign or update any of the properties of the view controller at all. I.e. updating label text, moving UIView etc... Here's what the code is looking like,

```
- (void) retrieveObject: (ScannedItem *) object 
  {
     if(object == NULL)
        nil;
     else
        self.scannedObject = object;

     NSLog(@"RETRIEVED IN V2: %@", self.scannedObject.itemName);
    [self performSelector:@selector(animateResults:) withObject:self afterDelay:0];
 }

- (void) refreshBarcode: sender 
 {
    NSLog(@"%@", detectionString);
    if(detectionString != nil) 
    {
       [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveOnlineData:) withObject:self afterDelay:0];
    }
 }

- (void) animateResults: sender
  {
     self.productName.text = @"Hey";

     if(resultsViewExpanded == YES)
      {
          NSLog(@"hiding");
          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                self.resultsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 531, self.resultsView.frame.size.width,  self.resultsView.frame.size.height);
           }];
     resultsViewExpanded = NO;

     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"showing");
         self.productName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.scannedObject.itemName];
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"ShowButtons" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

        self.resultsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 364, self.resultsView.frame.size.width,  self.resultsView.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        resultsViewExpanded = YES;
    }
  }
```

Ignore the horrific formatting, I have no clue what I'm doing with it. Thanks in advance for any support. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are updating, modifying the properties before view Load of second controller. Before View Load, if you update anything, it will not reflect, because update of properties will call after Controller navigated.